# What type of IEEE 802.11 standard (a, b, g, n, ac….) implemented in today's smartphones?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

IEEE 802.11 standard has several versions as a, b, g, n, ac... etc; since which standard is accommodated for smartphone's wifi feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts configurations are off-topic here. The answer will vary, depending on the vendor. SE has several sites covering different phone OSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smartphone these days are majorly powered by SOC from Qualcomm,Mediatek,Huawei Kirin. So it's purely depends upon the SOC in the smartphone. Very rarely smartphones have separate WiFi chipsets.

For instance the latest Qualcomm Snapdragaon 820 is with 802.11ac.

Just identify the SOC of your phone and google the datasheet/specifications.You will find your answers.